# Datatable - Additional columns cause side scroll to go past data options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I've recently converted my HTML table to a datatable with the JS function, and it worked perfectly with the existing 7 columns, However, adding more columns per the client's request has caused it to escape the side. So when I side scroll, it goes past the page # option, results per page option and the search. Here are 2 pictures showing the initial window and the window after I side scroll to the right a bit:

[image]
[image]

I'm hoping there's a fairly simple way to contain the actual table in an iframe or something so that sidescroll only affects the table itself, and not the datatable options. This is my first time using the datatable so I'm unsure if this can be done.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="dashboardTable" style="width:920px;">
<div style="overflow-x:auto;" >
<table id="mytable" style="border: 1px solid #468BBD; border-collapse: collapse; width:100%; margin:0 auto;">
<thead>
<tr style="border: 1px solid #468BBD;">
    <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">Service Preformed</th>
    <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">Work Order Number</th>
    <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">Date</th>
    <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">Utility</th>
    <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">Service Name</th>
    <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">Address</th>
    <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">Serial No.</th>
    <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">lowSideMIUNumArriv</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">lowSideMIUNumDepart</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">highSideMIUNumArriv</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">highSideMIUNumDepart</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">locationNotes</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">locationComments</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">WaterValveArriv</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">WaterValveDepart</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
?>

<tr>
    <td style="border-collapse: collapse; padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;"><? echo $row['workOrderType2'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border-collapse: collapse; padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;"><? echo $row['workOrderNum'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border-collapse: collapse; padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;"><? echo $row['date'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border-collapse: collapse; padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;"><? echo $row['utility'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border-collapse: collapse; padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;"><? echo $row['serviceName'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border-collapse: collapse; padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;"><? echo $row['address'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border-collapse: collapse; padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;"><?php echo '<a href="/dashboard-display?id='.$row['serialNumber'].'">'.$row['serialNumber'].'</a>'; ?>   </td>
    <td style="border-collapse: collapse; padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;"><? echo $row['lowSideMIUNumArriv'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border-collapse: collapse; padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;"><? echo $row['lowSideMIUNumDepart'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border-collapse: collapse; padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;"><? echo $row['highSideMIUNumArriv'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border-collapse: collapse; padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;"><? echo $row['highSideMIUNumDepart'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border-collapse: collapse; padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;"><? echo $row['locationNotes'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border-collapse: collapse; padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;"><? echo $row['locationComments'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border-collapse: collapse; padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;"><? echo $row['WaterValveArriv'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border-collapse: collapse; padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;"><? echo $row['WaterValveDepart'];?>&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
    <?}?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#mytable').DataTable();
 });
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the table's filters are generated after the table's html is rendered, you're going to have to add a wrapper with `overflow-x: auto` after the filters are added. See jQuery code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mytable').DataTable();
  $("#mytable").wrap("<div style='overflow-x: auto' />");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dashboardTable" style="width: 920px;">
  <div id="mytable_filter" class="dataTables_filter"><label>Search:<input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="mytable"></label></div>

  <table id="mytable" style="border: 1px solid #468BBD; border-collapse: collapse; width:100%;  margin:0 auto;">
    <thead>
      <tr style="border: 1px solid #468BBD;">
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">Service Preformed</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">Work Order Number</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">Date</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">Utility</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">Service Name</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">Address</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">Serial No.</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">lowSideMIUNumArriv</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">lowSideMIUNumDepart</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">highSideMIUNumArriv</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">highSideMIUNumDepart</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">locationNotes</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">locationComments</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">WaterValveArriv</th>
        <th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; border: 1px solid #468BBD;">WaterValveDepart</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Your welcome and don't forget your comments ;) God bless!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set fixed sizes for your table height and width. Make the table container overflow visible in both axes. Typically, the height and width of the container will smaller values than the table, as the container will represent your viewport..